# I am getting bubbles and a bulge at the bottom layer of my 3D print

Tags: 3d-models

I am printing ABS on an Ender 3 printer at a temperature of 240 °C on the nozzle and 110 °C on the bed. I am getting the following result:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried lower bed temperatures?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your bed is too hot because the bubbling is only on the bottom layer, if it was through out the entire print, I would say that it is your nozzle temp and you should do a temp tower, but because that isn't the case try lowering your bed temp

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue. First 2 to 4 layers looked god, than a trouble zone with 5 to 10 layers, and after that good again.
In my case the z-layer screws were not tight. During moving up I lost some steps due to the lose screws ...